# Can't use StepDefinitions from external assembly when using custom output path

Tags: specflow

I have problems setting up my specflow project. I want to have some step definitions in a shared assembly, so that I can reuse them.

I have two assemblies: A and B

Assembly A contains stepDefinitions which should be used by a feature file which is located in Assembly B.

Assembly B references Assembly A.
Assembly A contains the following specflow.json file:

```
 {
  "language": {
    "feature": "de-CH"
  }
}
```

Assembly B contains the following specflow.json file:

```
{
  "language": {
    "feature": "de-CH"
  },
  "stepAssemblies": [
    { "assembly": "A" }
  ]
}
```

This works perfectly fine as long as both assemblies have their output path set to  `bin\Debug\`

However, we generally have set up our solution so that all projects are built into a shared directory.
This speeds up compilation a lot, and we need this because our solution is huge.

So if I go to the Project Property Page of both projects A and B and open the Build tab, and change the Output Path to a shared path, e.g. `..\DebugBuild` then Specflow can no longer 
find the stepdefinitions. The test in Assembly B is now Inconclusive and the following output is shown:

> No matching step definition found for one or more steps.

How can I use external step definitions when I want to use shared output directory?

Best Regards

Matthias

Comment: Is there another project that happens to create an assembly with the same name, so you step definitions get overwritten?

Comment: @GregBurghardt no this is not the case

Comment: Are all the assemblies showing up in the shared output path?